# Split screen design layout, one half of scrollable content has a huge white space area, unable to remove whitespace

Tags: html, css

I am developing a website where the body is split into two sections using Materialize grid. On the left side the website has a fixed image that wont change, the right side has content that a user can scroll up and down on. There is also a fixed navbar and fixed footer. Here is the  [layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YbEuC.jpg)

Here you can see as you scroll down where the whitespace starts [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i3Ht3.jpg)

I want the right side to not have any white space and just have the div content show. I looked through each element through the inspect tool and saw no additional padding or margins. I am wondering if the fixed left side is adding pixels to the bottom of the left side?

Here is my index.html `

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no"/>
  <title> Sequel Seattle Apartments </title>

  <!-- CSS  -->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link href="css/materialize.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>
  <link href="css/style.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen,projection"/>

</head>
<body>
  <nav class="white" role="navigation">
    <div class="nav-wrapper container">
      <a id="logo-container" href="#" class="brand-logo">
        <img class="mainlogo" src="logo_navy.png" alt="Sequel Apartments Seattle"/>
      </a>
      <ul class="bigbuttoncta right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Apply Now</a></li>
        <li><a class="waves-effect waves-light btn">Contact Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="#section1">Aparmtents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section2">Sequel Lifestyle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section3">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section4">Amenities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#section5">Gallery</a></li>
      </ul>

      <ul id="nav-mobile" class="side-nav">
        <li><a href="#">Aparmtents</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Sequel Lifestyle</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Location</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Amenities</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Gallery</a></li>      </ul>
      <a href="#" data-activates="nav-mobile" class="button-collapse"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
    </div>
  </nav>

<!-- START OF CONTENT -->
<div id="allcontentfields" class="row">
  <!-- Left Hand side of the screen, static content -->
  <div class="col s5 leftsection">
    <div id="index-banner" class="parallax-container">
        <img src="background1.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 1">
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- Right hand side of the screen, all dynamic content -->
  <div class="col s7 offset-s5 rightsection" > 


    <!-- SECTION 1 -->
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="section1">
      <div class="row">
        <h1>Text goes here </h1>
      </div>
    </div>


    <!-- SECTION 2 -->
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="section2">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
          <div class="section no-pad-bot">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          <div class="parallax"><img src="background2.jpg" alt="Unsplashed background img 2"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SECTION 3 -->
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="section3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
          <div class="section no-pad-bot">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SECTION 4 -->
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="section4">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
          <div class="section no-pad-bot">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- SECTION 5 -->
    <div class="section scrollspy" id="section5">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="parallax-container valign-wrapper">
          <div class="section no-pad-bot">
            <div class="container">
              <div class="row center">
                <h5 class="header col s12 light">A modern responsive front-end framework based on Material Design</h5>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

</div>
  </div>
</div> 


<!-- FOOTER SECTION -->
  <footer class="page-footer teal">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col l6 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Company Bio</h5>
          <p class="grey-text text-lighten-4">We are a team of college students working on this project like it's our full time job. Any amount would help support and continue development on this project and is greatly appreciated.</p>


        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Settings</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col l3 s12">
          <h5 class="white-text">Connect</h5>
          <ul>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 1</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 2</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 3</a></li>
            <li><a class="white-text" href="#!">Link 4</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="footer-copyright">
      <div class="container">
      Made by <a class="brown-text text-lighten-3" href="http://herocreativemedia.com">Hero Creative Media, LLC</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>


  <!--  Scripts-->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/materialize.js"></script>
  <script src="js/init.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
`
```

Here is the CSS, I am using Materialize so they have a css file as well but I haven't messed with it.

```
/* Custom Stylesheet */
/**
 * Use this file to override Materialize files so you can update
 * the core Materialize files in the future
 *
 * Made By MaterializeCSS.com
 */
html, body {
  margin:0;
  padding: 0;
}

nav ul a,
nav .brand-logo {
  color: #444;
}

nav {
 position: fixed;
 width: 100%;

}





.col {
  position:relative;
  margin-top: 125px;

}

.row .col.s5 {
  margin-left:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  padding:0;
}

.row .col.offset-s5 {
  padding:0;
  height: auto;
}

.leftsection {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding:0;
  overflow:hidden;
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;

}

.rightsection {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
  margin-top: 200px;
  padding:0;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: auto;



}

#section1 {
  position:relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding:0;
}

#section2 {
  position:relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#section3 {
  position:relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  background-color:blue;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#section4 {
  position:relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  background-color:yellow;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#section5 {
  position:relative;
  height: 700px;
  width: 100%;
  padding:0;
  background-color:orange;
  z-index: -1;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}


.mainlogo {
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: -50px;
  margin-top: 40px;

}

.bigbuttoncta {
  margin-top: 10px;

}

.bigbuttoncta li {
  margin: 20px;
}



p {
  line-height: 2rem;
}

.button-collapse {
  color: #26a69a;
}

.parallax-container {
  min-height: 780px;
  line-height: 0;
  height: auto;
  color: rgba(255,255,255,.9);
  z-index: -1;
  }
  .parallax-container .section {
    width: 100%;
  }

@media only screen and (max-width : 992px) {
  .parallax-container .section {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40%;
  }
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 10%;
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width : 600px) {
  #index-banner .section {
    top: 0;
  }
}

.icon-block {
  padding: 0 15px;
}
.icon-block .material-icons {
  font-size: inherit;
}

footer.page-footer {
  margin-top: 100%;
  display:block;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured out that it was my footer.page-footer  had a margin top that was set to 100% so in essence created a huge sroll that was showing on one half of the screen since the other half was fixed. I removed that and I am all set.

Note to self....delete the stupid CSS you put in when trying to figure stuff out.